# How to not let outlook or gmail not to change the rgb color in dark mode?

Tags: html, css, templates, outlook, darkmode

I don't want outlook or gmail to change my background-color of rgb(255, 80, 0) to rgb(208, 33, 0).My background is a dark one,therefore email clients are changing it into a slightly lighter or darker shade of the original color.I have tried using gradient but it doesn't work with every client. Can anyone help?

CSS for overwriting outlook inline css.

IMAGES FOR REFERENCE:

1.[DARK MODE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fciWz.png)
2.[LIGHT MODE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXcTw.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackExchange! Can you please provide a screenshot(censored if needed) to show what you mean? so we know more what the question is about. and what does the last sentence mean?  (the `CSS for overwriting outlook inline css.`)

Comment: Edited the post with two reference image